# Django: decorator in class based view

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-decorators, django-1.4

I want to restrict access to a particular view so that only AJAX requests are accepted, so I implemented the following decorator:

```
def require_ajax(func):
    def decorator(func):
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.is_ajax():
                return HttpResponseBadRequest()
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner

    return decorator
```

This works perfectly in function views, but I cannot figure out how to use it in class based views. I have tried [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) but got errors, I assume due the old version of Django I am using.

And well, my class-based view:

```
class AjaxView(TemplateView):
  template_name = '...'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    return context

  @method_decorator(require_ajax)
  def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(AjaxView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What errors exactly? Can't really well help you without knowing the problem. Using the `method_decorator` is an OK approach, however you might want to check out the documentation for that method form Django 1.4. https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views.html?highlight=method_decorator#decorating-the-class

Comment: You'll need to make a mixin for CBV's - The same way `login_required` and `LoginRequiredMixin` work

Comment: @makaveli the error is just about the kwargs, it says there are unexpected  kwargs (which I am using in `get_context_data`).

Comment: @Sayse Could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Source for LRM](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py#L49) - Essentially, you can either, apply your decorator to the `dispatch` method for every view that needs it, or make a mixin similar to this then its just `class AjaxView(MyMixin, TemplateView)`

Comment: @Sayse alright I get it now. However when trying to apply the method decorator to the `dispatch` method I am getting the error I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not familiar with django 1.4, you should probably add the error details to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing the decorator differently solved the issue:

```
def require_ajax(func):
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorator
```